# Visual Studio 2005 Custom Build for Qt

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++

i've the following in the custom build property of every header file that uses Q_OBJECT:

```
Command Line: $(THIRDPARTY_DIR)\qt\4.7.0\win32-vc10\bin\moc.exe $(InputFileName) -o moc\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_$(InputName).cpp
Description: ################### moc'ing $(InputFileName)
Outputs: moc\$(ConfigurationName)\moc_$(InputName).cpp
```

This generates the necessary moc files. I now want to ask visual studio to compile and link these too, to my other source files. Presently i'm using 
`#include "moc\{Release OR Debug}\moc_Whatever.cpp"#` statements in any of the files to force compilation and linking. Evidently i have to keep changing my #include according to debug or release build (i cannot discard $(ConfiguarationName) during moc file generation above for reasons). Plus i dont like the idea of writing this `#include` in the source files just for the purposes of compilation and linking.

Is there any build step in properties anywhere where i can mention what files will be generated in future and to compile and link them when they are available (`VS2005`)?

(i cannot use QtPlugin right now)

Answer (score 0):

You simply add those files to the project, my project structure usually looks like this (in Visual Studio Solution Explorer):

```
  Solution
    |
    +- Project1
          |
          +- Generated Files
          +- Header Files
          +- Source Files
```

In Generated Files, I include References to both, the Debug and the Release moc_xxx.cpp and qrc_xxx.cpp files. For the Debug files, you need to set "Exclude from Build" to true for the Release references and vice versa.

That's pretty much the same what the plugin does.

Comment: thanks! just one more question: i've to 1st build the project which would give linker errors but by then the moc files will have been generated. then i `add existing items` in the `GeneratedFiles` filter that i created and then re-run the build process for successful build. for moc'ing i'm using VS variables like `$(InputFileName)` etc so i just copy paste the custom build from one `.h` file to another. is there a process to automate the compilation and linking of generated moc files instead of manually adding them like i'm doing?

Comment: Actually that's precisely what the Plugin does! Why can't you use it?